# Triggers in Postgres: Access NEW fields by name at runtime

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres, someone knows how to substitute the value of the variable in a NEW.variable in a trigger?

For instance, I have a variable with value order_code. I want to execute NEW.variable so that it's getting in fact NEW.order_code.

In detailed:

I have a function to obtain the primary key column of a table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getPrimaryKey(_table_name VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS SETOF VARCHAR(50) AS $$
DECLARE 
    primary_key VARCHAR(50);
BEGIN
    FOR primary_key IN SELECT a.attname
        FROM   pg_index i
        JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = i.indrelid
                             AND a.attnum = ANY(i.indkey)
        WHERE  i.indrelid = _table_name::regclass
        AND    i.indisprimary LOOP
        RETURN NEXT primary_key;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then I have a trigger to collect some info when an INSERT is done in a table. The procedure in the trigger is called from several triggers from different tables. That's why it's so generic and I have this need.

What I want is to obtain the primary key of the object inserted.

```
CREATE FUNCTION logAudit()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE primary_key VARCHAR(50);
BEGIN
    primary_key := getprimarykey(TG_TABLE_NAME::VARCHAR(50));
    INSERT INTO test VALUES (TG_TABLE_NAME);
    INSERT INTO test VALUES (NEW.primary_key);
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER audit_in_client
AFTER INSERT ON tb_client
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE logAudit();
```

The NEW.primary_key is what is causing me issues. I expect primary_key to be the column name of the source table where the insert happened. What I want in NEW.primary_key is to actually use the value in the variable.

Comment: Are you using pl/pgsql?  If so, please show us some of it.  Is your trigger a AFTER trigger?  If so, anything you do to NEW just gets thrown away.

Comment: Sure, editing the post

Comment: Thanks! Looks good, but still not working. Got this error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$2"
LINE 1: SELECT $1.$2

Comment: Edited my answer. Your question was changed a bit since I wrote the first version :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example of anonymous pl/pgsql block which doing something what you want:

```
do $$
declare
  v pg_database = (pg_database) from pg_database where datname = 'template1';
  fname text = 'datname';
  n text;
begin
  n := to_jsonb(v)->>fname;
  raise info '%', n;
end $$;
```

Output:

```
INFO:  template1
```

It is working example. In your trigger function it could be something like

```
declare
  pk_name text;
  pk_value text;
begin
  pk_name := getprimarykey(TG_TABLE_NAME::VARCHAR(50));
  pk_value := to_jsonb(NEW) ->> pk_name;
  -- Do what you want with pk_value here
  return null;
end $$;
```